# Python module import error with command prompt of Windows 7

Tags: python, import, module, command-prompt

I have a script in Python where i import several modules

```
from __future__ import division
import os
import glob
import sys
import tempfile
import shutil
import math
import datetime
import gdal
import random
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import box
from liblas import file
```

when i use an IDLE (es: PyCharm or PyScripter) i have no problem to import the external modules (gdal, shapely.geometry, and liblas). When i run the script i got this error message

```
C:\PythonScript\myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PythonScript\myscript.py", line 10, in <module>
import gdal
ImportError: No module named gdal
where

print(gdal.__file__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdal.pyc
and

print(sys.path)
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2.7.3\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\progressbar-2.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PythonScript']
```

i installed gdal using Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages using an file *.exe.

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one instance of python on your machine? it's quite possible the instance you are using doesnt have the modules you need. Especially as Pyscripter has access to both internal and remote python engines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the path of Python install and site-packages. if something wrong with that, your system might not be able to find the modules and site-packages which may cause such errors.